# Finding Gaussian function with specific level curves

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I’d like to find a Gaussian function with specific level curves as attached in the image, that is; the first quadrant with $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$, symmetric around $y=x$ and somewhat egg shaped (preferably converging to a ridge by manipulating any of the constants below). I’ve tried the following function: $$f(x,y)=e^{-a(x-0.5)^2-b(x-0.5)(y-0.5)-c(y-0.5)^2}$$ See [this](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/ryhuqf5q) Geogebra illustration. What are the optimal values of the constants $a,b,c$ to get the level curves as shown in the image?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $a=c=30$, and $b=-50$. To be a Gaussian, you must have $a,c>0$. Since you want it to be symmetric around $x=y$, you get $a=c$. Start by setting $b=0$. You will get a Gaussian with a circular symmetry. If you increase $b$, you will deform the Gaussian such that the long axis is parallel to $y=-x$. So in order to get it to have the long axis along $y=x$ you need to have a negative $b$. Also note that it can't be too negative or too positive. (in the limit $b=\pm 2a$ you get a long ridge)

Comment: Suppose one would like to extend this to 3D, that is construct level surfaces. Would these surfaces be ellipsoids and what is the extention of the function if it should remain symmetric around the plane $y=x$ and centered at $(0.5,0.5,0.5)$?

Comment: You would need to add three more terms to the exponent, one for $z^2$, one for $xz$, and one for $yz$. You want the last two to be equal.

Comment: So something like this $f(x,y,z)=e^{-30(x-0.5)^2-30(y-0.5)^2-30(z-0.5)^2+50(x-0.5)(y-0.5)(z-0.5)}$?

Comment: The last term should be replaced by something like $50(x-0.5)(y-0.5)+30(x-0.5)(z-0.5)+30(y-0.5)(z-0.5)$

Comment: Sorry to bother again. If one would like the level curve in the above image to be symmetric around $y=0.5$ or $x=0.5$, are there any terms that need to be omitted then?

Comment: You mean that the constant level curves are circles?

Comment: No, keeping the level curves ellipses, but letting the semi-major axes align with the $y$-axis and the semi-minor axes align with $x$-axis, or the other way around.

Comment: Then use $b=0$. $b$ is a term that describes how you rotate the ellipse.